# What does this expression mean - "weigh in two great limits"?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean by *weigh in two great limits*?

> He had that magical spot that he was able to **weigh in two great limits**
> and take the lead with almost a five pound margin.

This story is about a fishing competition.

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrasal verb [weigh in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weigh-in)?

Comment: @sunny Please [edit] your question to include the citation for where you found that quote, and a link too if it's available online.

Comment: @Stuart F, that use of weigh-in is for things like boxing,  where there are different weight categories. People of approximately the same weight compete against each other. You wouldn't have someone weighing 100 lb competing against a 180 lb opponent.   I doubt they do that in fishing competitions.   Probably something to do with weighing the fish for judging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this depends on the rules in question.  A "limit" could mean a limit of fish (either number or weight) per session to prevent over-fishing.

In this case, it's probably a fish count limit, forcing the sportsmen to target larger fish (harder to catch) rather than many smaller fish (which are typically easier to catch).

So an angler catching 10 fish of 10kg each would win over another angler who caught 10 fish of 5kg each, and win the match by a 5kg margin.